# Cannot switch to buffer

Tags: buffers, debugging

When I hit `C-x b` to switch to buffer I receive:

> Symbol's function definition is void: help--symbol-class.

I'm on Linux with Emacs 27.1 (build 1 - GTK 3.24.24)

Comment: Does it happen from `emacs -Q`? If not, I suggest you figure out what command you have bound to `C-x b` by typing `C-h k C-x b`.

Answer (score 1):

The `help--symbol-class` function is a standard part of Emacs, but only since version 28.1, so you evidentially have code in your config which is incompatible with the version of Emacs you're using.

I suspect you're using some package which purports to be compatible with 27.1 but has inadvertently introduced some code which depends on newer versions.  (And is explicitly calling a function which, by naming convention, isn't intended to be part of the API; but maybe there was no better alternative.)

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `toggle-debug-on-error` should track down the culprit.

(If you don't know how to proceed after triggering the debugger, then copy and paste the backtrace into your question.)